# I'm a bit unsure on correct comma placement in the following sentence. Parenthetical or not?

Tags: commas

I'm not sure if the phrase 'indeed necessary' is parenthetical in the following example and thus requires two commas or if I can/should write it with a single comma after 'valuable'.

1)It allows religious freedom to be understood as a valuable, indeed (a) necessary cultural achievement.

2) It allows religious freedom to be understood as a valuable, indeed a necessary, cultural achievement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parenthetical in this particular situation would be completely stylistic. Personally, I think your sentence would flow best without commas and instead with "and."
*It allows religious freedom to be understood as a valuable and indeed necessary cultural achievement.*
If you want to keep the commas, I would change "indeed" to "in fact."
Inserting a parenthetical kind of implies the insertion of a separate piece of information which "indeed" only affirms the information you're presenting. "In fact" creates a more clear segment of thought.
*It allows religious freedom to be understood as a valuable, in fact, necessary cultural achievement.*
(You can technically insert a comma between necessary and cultural, but that's up to you)

Comment: Thanks. I like that suggestion with 'and' and upvoted. I'm still interested to know if the first variant is acceptable grammatically.